# Как правильно расставить знаки препинания? И почему?

Tags: пунктуация, как, оборот-с-как

"каждый раз как будто первый раз"

Comment: Приведите полное _предложение_ - без этого нельзя ответить однозначно.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не хватает контекста. Фраза написана с маленькой буквы, в конце нет точки, что предполагает оторванность от предыдущих и последующих слов. Соответственно, возможны разные варианты пунктуации.

Если же это самостоятельное предложение, то запятая не нужна:

***Каждый раз как будто первый раз.***

[**Сравнительный оборот**](https://old-rozental.online/punctum_uk.php?pid=159)

> 2. Сравнительные обороты с союзами ***будто, как будто, словно, нежели, чем, точно, что*** не выделяются запятыми, если они входят в состав сказуемого или тесно связаны с ним по смыслу:
>
> *Вода в заливе **как будто чёрная тушь***.
> *Огни фонарей **словно маяки***.

В Нацкорпусе русского языка есть почти идентичное предложение:

*― Каждый раз как будто в первый раз.* [И. Меттер. Накануне (1979)]